# How to use python to graph a 4-d graph for imaginary inputs of quadratic functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph, 3d

I am a highschool senior with no coding experience, but im trying to code a matplotlib 3d graph with a color gradient as a fourth dimension to graph the function:

> *f(x) = x^2 + 1*

for all real and complex values (a + b*i*) of *x*, which would require me to have four dimensions: the real part *x* of (x + bi) of x [Now referred to as X], the imaginary part *bi* of (x + bi) [Now referred to as W], the real part *y* of (y + bi) [Now referred to as Y],  and the imaginary part *bi* of (y + bi) [Now referred to as Z].

Basically the input will be *x*, in the format **(X + W)**, and the output will be *f(x)*, in the format **(Y + Z)**. I want the graph to have the axes X, Y, and Z, with W being represented as a color gradient on the surface of the graph. Z and W are imaginary numbers b*cmath.sqrt(-1). I would want a range of (-20, 20) on all parameters.

I have python and anaconda on my laptop, pls help. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my solution:**

```py
# Import packages
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   # Needed to create 3D plots
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib notebook                     # Uncomment this if using Jupyter

# Define function
def fun(x):
    # Note: x is a complex() object, and * and + are defined for complex numbers
    return x*x + 1

# Create 1x1 figure with 3 axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define grid of x and w using a step of 0.05
X = W = np.arange(-20.0, 20.0, 0.05)
X, W = np.meshgrid(X,W)
complexVals = X + 1j*W      # Convert X/W grid into complex numbers

# Call the function on the complex numbers and extract the real/imag parts
Y_Z = fun(complexVals)
Y = Y_Z.real
Z = Y_Z.imag

# Create colormap for W
color_dimension = W
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)

# Create surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=fcolors, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False,
                linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('X (Re)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (Re)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z = f(x) (Im)')

# Create colorbar and set title
cbr = plt.colorbar(m)
cbr.ax.set_title('W')

# Show plot with colorbar
plt.show()
```

**Here is the output:** 
[image: 3D_Plot]

**However, if you are using Anaconda, I strongly suggest adding this code into a Jupyter Notebook. That what you can get an interactive plot.** 
It is already installed with Anaconda and you start it by typing `jupyter notebook` into your Anaconda prompt.

Comment: is jupyter notebook still the same language tho?

Comment: what does '# Note: x is a complex() object, and * and + are defined for complex numbers' mean

Comment: @HarleyGlayzer I am just denoting the `x` argument that is being passed into the `fun` function is NOT simply an integer, but rather a complex number and that Python understands * and + for complex numbers. Also, the result is also a complex number.

Comment: @JacobK do you know why I'm getting this error by using your code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417129/erorrcant-create-mpf-from-an-array-while-3d-plotting-a-function-with-incomplet?noredirect=1#comment126233593_71417129