# Erorr:can't create mpf from an array while 3D plotting a function with incomplete gamma function

Tags: python, plot, mpmath

I would like to display my complex function in the complex domain, but I have a problem. I get the following error message: `cannot create mpf from array`  The code is simple and I have tried to show where the problem is. I think that my `mpmath` cannot work with `complex`  in this form to create an array. What can solve the problem of this library with my imaginary part?

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   # Needed to create 3D plots
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib notebook
# Uncomment this if using Jupyter
def Laplace_Max(s):
    #mp.dps = 100
    A= s**(5/4)/ (
        0.00480931 + 
        0.0244077*s**(1/4) + 
        0.0129056*mp.exp(-35*s)*s**(1/4) + 
        0.00329167*mp.exp(0.707997*s)*s**(1/4) * mp.gammainc(0.0, 35.708*s,mp.inf, regularized=True) - 
        0.00530593*mp.gammainc(1.25, 35*s,mp.inf,   regularized=True)
    )
    return A


# Create 1x1 figure with 3 axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define grid of x and w using a step of 0.05
X = W = np.arange(-20.0, 20.0, 0.05)
X, W = np.meshgrid(X,W)
complexVals = X + 1j*W      # Convert X/W grid into complex numbers

# Call the function on the complex numbers and extract the real/imag parts
##################PROBLEM IS HERE#############
Y_Z = Laplace_Max(complexVals)
##################PROBLEM IS HERE#############
Y = Y_Z.real
Z = Y_Z.imag

# Create colormap for W
color_dimension = W
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)

# Create surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=fcolors, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False,
                linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('X (Re)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (Re)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z = f(x) (Im)')

# Create colorbar and set title
cbr = plt.colorbar(m)
cbr.ax.set_title('W')

# Show plot with colorbar
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
cannot create mpf from array([[ 700.  +700.j  ,  698.25+700.j  ,  696.5 +700.j  , ...,
        -694.75+700.j  , -696.5 +700.j  , -698.25+700.j  ],
       [ 700.  +698.25j,  698.25+698.25j,  696.5 +698.25j, ...,
        -694.75+698.25j, -696.5 +698.25j, -698.25+698.25j],
       [ 700.  +696.5j ,  698.25+696.5j ,  696.5 +696.5j , ...,
        -694.75+696.5j , -696.5 +696.5j , -698.25+696.5j ],
       ...,
       [ 700.  -694.75j,  698.25-694.75j,  696.5 -694.75j, ...,
        -694.75-694.75j, -696.5 -694.75j, -698.25-694.75j],
       [ 700.  -696.5j ,  698.25-696.5j ,  696.5 -696.5j , ...,
        -694.75-696.5j , -696.5 -696.5j , -698.25-696.5j ],
       [ 700.  -698.25j,  698.25-698.25j,  696.5 -698.25j, ...,
        -694.75-698.25j, -696.5 -698.25j, -698.25-698.25j]])
```

Comment: When asking about an error show the whole error, with traceback.  Your "tried to show where" was inadequate, though I can easily guess the nature of the problem,  You created a `ComplexVals` array and passed to a function that tried to use in an `mp.exp` function.

Comment: Why are you using `mpmath`?  Isn't `scipy/numpy` good enough?

Comment: @hpaulj There is an incomplete gamma function, which is rather presecis in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `complex`; it's the array.

You can use `mp` with python scalars:

```
In [32]: mp.exp(1)
Out[32]: mpf('2.7182818284590451')
```

but not arrays:

```
In [33]: mp.exp(np.array([1]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <module>
----> 1 mp.exp(np.array([1]))

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py:989, in PythonMPContext._wrap_libmp_function.<locals>.f(x, **kwargs)
    987 def f(x, **kwargs):
    988     if type(x) not in ctx.types:
--> 989         x = ctx.convert(x)
    990     prec, rounding = ctx._prec_rounding
    991     if kwargs:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py:648, in PythonMPContext.convert(ctx, x, strings)
    646 if isinstance(x, complex):
    647     return ctx.make_mpc((from_float(x.real), from_float(x.imag)))
--> 648 if type(x).__module__ == 'numpy': return ctx.npconvert(x)
    649 if isinstance(x, numbers.Rational): # e.g. Fraction
    650     try: x = rational.mpq(int(x.numerator), int(x.denominator))

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py:681, in PythonMPContext.npconvert(ctx, x)
    679 if isinstance(x, np.complexfloating):
    680     return ctx.make_mpc((from_npfloat(x.real), from_npfloat(x.imag)))
--> 681 raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))

TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([1])
```

Again the scalar:

```
In [34]: mp.exp(np.array([1]).item())
Out[34]: mpf('2.7182818284590451')
```

not a list either:

```
In [35]: mp.exp(np.array([1]).tolist())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <module>
----> 1 mp.exp(np.array([1]).tolist())

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py:989, in PythonMPContext._wrap_libmp_function.<locals>.f(x, **kwargs)
    987 def f(x, **kwargs):
    988     if type(x) not in ctx.types:
--> 989         x = ctx.convert(x)
    990     prec, rounding = ctx._prec_rounding
    991     if kwargs:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py:669, in PythonMPContext.convert(ctx, x, strings)
    667     try: return ctx.make_mpf(from_Decimal(x, prec, rounding))
    668     except: pass
--> 669 return ctx._convert_fallback(x, strings)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp.py:634, in MPContext._convert_fallback(ctx, x, strings)
    632     else:
    633         raise ValueError("can only create mpf from zero-width interval")
--> 634 raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))

TypeError: cannot create mpf from [1]
```